# Power apps, Choices aren't showing up

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

When doing my power app, how come I have "Off" as a choice?
My data is connected to sharepoint list - and I have choices for each question (yes or no are my choices). Why arent my choices being reflected in my power app?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a control for a toggle in view mode with the underlying field value being "false". This is the default setting of the control, but it can be configured to show other words. Mind you that the toggle control expects a boolean data type, not a choice field, and it will not work with words in a choice list.

It's not the control that you would typically use for a SharePoint Choice field. A SharePoint Choice field is normally represented by a Combobox.

You say that "yes" and "no" are your choices, but are you using a Choice field with the words "yes" and "no" in the options, or are you using a Yes/No field that shows the words "yes" and "no" in the SharePoint view? There is a difference.

**Edit after comment:** If you change the data type of a SharePoint field, you need to remove the old card in PowerApps, save and publish the PowerApp, then re-open PowerApp and add the field again. It will then have the correct control in the card.

You may want to wait a moment between closing and opening PowerApp again, because it can take some time for SharePoint changes to "arrive" in PowerApps. Specifically changes to data types need more than just a data source refresh.

Comment: Before I was using the option "Yes/No" in the sharepoint list, but I changed it now to "Choices" where I made the 2 choices Yes or No.

Comment: Well, that's a different data type, then, and requires a different control. I added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: thanks, testing it out now. This is annoying as I have to redo my font changes to each card again. Is there a way to do a mass change to fonts in each of my cards?

Comment: No easy way, especially not when you load new cards.